# what is the physical explanation for additive drag?

Tags: jet, drag, propulsion

from what i understand, additive drag is not really drag. it is a way to account for the variation of inlet condition due to conservation of mass.
 but i still don't get why it create drag(negative thrust) when bookkeeping the thrust value of all parts of jet engine/ducted fan

can anyone explain this for me

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29376/17780

Comment: The question is perfectly clear. Why do people flag it as unclear?